# Change default in-call & out-call ui or theme

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Is there any app available in the store that lets me change the default in-call & out-call ui or theme of my kitkat?

Answer (score 1):

There are several apps available on PlayStore like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wroclawstudio.screencaller) or [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androminigsm.fscifree). However, you can't change the full "Theme" as such on Kitkat. You can change the look and feel of your home screens, caller screen, etc with the help of launchers (Nova Launcher, Themer, etc).

Comment: :Is there any free app with bigscreen options for all contacts?